# cygwin: vim in mc not coloring

Tags: vim, cygwin, midnight-commander

I have a setup using cygwin with midnight commander and vim. I have a proper .vimrc in my home folder, which works fine if I start up vim directly on the console. Now I also want mc to use vim, so I disabled "use internal viewer/editor". I also aliased vi to vim in my .bashrc and the alias is working properly.

The Problem is: when I open vim via mc, coloring is not working. If I manually try to enable syntax highlighting (syntax on), I get

```
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version
```

If I start vim directly, everything is working as it should.
My .vimrc and .bashrc look the following:

```
~/.vimrc
set nocompatible
set nocp
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set term=xterm-256
syntax on
set hlsearch
set t_Sb=m
set t_Sf=m
set autoindent
set cindent
set smartindent
colorscheme distinguished
set t_Co=256

~/.bashrc
export EDITOR vim
alias vi="/usr/bin/vim"
[..other stuff..]
```

I've also tried to alias vi and explicitly setting the Terminal to xterm-256color, which cygwin uses in my case.

Same setup on debian is working fine though..

Comment: I have tried your settings (except `colorscheme distinguished` which I do not have) in a clean, updated Cygwin installation. I do not observe the problem. You do not need `xterm-256` which is for 256 color xterm variant instead of 16 standard ones. ------ As a test please try to rename: `mv /usr/bin/vi /usr/bin/vi-dontuse` and start `mc` again. ------ Also in the `vim` instance without highlighting try to run `:version` and add the result to the question. ------ Additionally please list the process tree with the problematic `vim`: `pstree -alpsuU`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh. Guess what: There was a missing '='

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

Only found it because mc did not start the editor when moving vi to vi-dontuse

Comment: :-)) I did not notice the missing `=`. --- Yesterday I also forgot about one thing. The alias `alias vi="/usr/bin/vim"` was useless because **1.** Aliases are not expanded in a non-interactive shell by default. **2.** They are not inherited by sub-processes and `.bashrc` is automatically executed only during start of an interactive bash. **3.** Contrary to variables aliases have no sense to non-shell processes. (Anyway they are not inherited.)

Comment: And learned something again :) Thanks for your thoughts. If you commit an answer, I'll mark it.